# How and where to add google analytics tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics

Creating a single page responsive site in drupal 7.While trying to enable google analytics module,came through certain doubts. While registering our site with google analytics they gave us a tracking id (a js snippet)
Can anyone tell me after enabling module is it necessary to add the snippet ?
If its necessary ,then where to add the snippet in which .tpl file in drupal?

Answer (score 5):

Easiest and most admin-friendly way is to use [Google Analytics module](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics):

> Adds the Google Analytics web statistics tracking system to your website.

Just install it, turn it on and configure.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [drupal.org](https://drupal.org/files/images/Google%20Analytics%20Admin%20Section%20Screenshot.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks Molot for your response .After enabling and configuring the google analytics module ,and signing up with google analytics,showing an message as tracking not installed. Hoping we don't need to paste the snippet code in any of .tpl files!!

Comment: @NijiMonachan give Google couple of hours. It's servers are busy, they don't keep a real-time eye on your site to know if you did it or not. Next time they'll have a glance, they'll tell.

Comment: @NijiMonachan also, and I know how it sounds, **be sure to clear caches**. If Drupal has page without GA in cache, GA will not work, simple as this.